# Problem with the 'deflate' parameter of Pymupdf and Acrobat Reader

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, acrobat, pymupdf

My program is redacting sensible information from PDF files. While saving the redacted PDF, I'm passing a few parameters to avoid exporting oversized files :

```
doc.save(
    file_path,
    permissions=fitz.PDF_PERM_PRINT, 
    owner_pw="owner",
    encryption=fitz.PDF_ENCRYPT_AES_256,
    garbage=3, 
    deflate=True
)
```

Those PDF files are aimed to be opened by Adobe Acrobat Reader (Version 2021.007.20099).

**Problem is :** when I open the redacted files with Acrobat, some files throw a pop up window with the following message :

```
An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. 
Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.
```

If I click the `OK` button to dismiss the warning message, I can go through the file without any visible problem.

How can I get rid of this warning message ?

**While debugging** I realised the problem was solved when I pass `deflate=False` as parameter. But this is not a viable solution since file sizes after redaction are sometimes 10 times bigger than the original files.

Here's what the [official documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html) says about `deflate`:

```
deflate (bool) – Deflate (compress) uncompressed streams.
```

The `garbage` parameter doesn't seem to have an impact on this issue, and the remaining parameters are essential to the process thus they cannot be changed.

This might be a problem with overlapping of redaction (being applied several times on the same x,y coordinates) but some of those cases don't raise errors.

Would appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks.

### To Reproduce the error:

The error can be reproduced with the following command :

`python redact_pdf.py test_file.pdf`

- `redact_pdf.py` : script to launch (see below)
- `test_file.pdf` : PDF file to redact -> [test_file.pdf](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/files/10130886/test_file.pdf)

*NB : both files have to be in the same directory*

**redact_pdf.py**

```
import sys
import fitz


def redact_pdf(file_path: str) -> None:
    """
    This file redacts all text "blocks" containing "XX" by deleting the initial text
    and covering its surface (bounding box) with a black rectangle. The redacted PDF
    file is named and exported as follows : "file_path_ANON.pdf"

    Args:
        file_path: path to the file to redact, passed as a command line parameter

    Returns:
        None
    """
    try:
        doc = fitz.open(file_path)
        redacted = False

        for page in doc:
            page.wrap_contents()
            blocks = page.get_text("blocks")

            for block in blocks:
                if "XX" in block[4]:
                    page.add_redact_annot(block[:4], fill=(0, 0, 0))
                    if page.apply_redactions(images=fitz.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_REMOVE):
                        redacted = True

        if redacted:
            file_path = file_path.replace(".pdf", "_ANON.pdf")
            doc.save(
                file_path,
                permissions=fitz.PDF_PERM_PRINT,
                owner_pw="owner",
                encryption=fitz.PDF_ENCRYPT_AES_256,
                garbage=4,
                deflate=True
            )
            print("Redacted file :", file_path)
        else:
            print("No redaction detected")

    except BaseException as err:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        print(f"{type(err)} (line {exc_tb.tb_lineno}) : {err}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    redact_pdf(sys.argv[1])
```

In my case, this results in a [corrupted file](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/files/10130954/test_file_ANON.pdf) that raises the warning message cited before **when opened with Acrobat Reader**.

Note that opening the file in the browser doesn't raise a warning message. Unfortunately, I cannot change the default behaviour of PDF opening, thus I have to stick with Acrobat Reader.

[Link to Github issue](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/2095)

Comment: This would be worthwhile submitting an issue on PyMuPDF's issue management on Github, https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues. I hope you can share a reproducing file!
What happens if you do not encrypt?

Comment: Thanks, will do that.

Comment: Can you share an example file before and after processing that illustrates the issue?

Comment: Before : https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDuvN.png
After https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHVIS.png

Comment: I meant example PDFs, not bitmaps, to allow analysis of the pdf internals. Unfortunately stack overflow does not allow for other file upload than images, so you can only post a link to share a PDF here , e.g. a link of a public share on a file sharing platform.

Comment: Good point, didn't realize the PDF were converted to PNG. Here are links to [original file](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/files/10130886/test_file.pdf) and [redacted file](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/files/10130954/test_file_ANON.pdf). I've also updated the post with steps to reproduce the error.

Comment: Thanks @KJ it does. I assume you compressed it with PDF XChange Editor ? Is there another open source tool you'd have in mind ? Also worth precising that I tried compressing the streams with another library. I set `deflate=False` to create uncompressed but healthy PDF files. Then I opened the files with PyPDF2 library and regenerate them using a lossless compression method "which uses the zlib/deflate compression method". This brings back the same warning message.

Comment: To everyone's info: the problem does no longer occur in the latest version 1.21.0 of PyMuPDF.

Answer (score 1):

According to Jorj McKie's comment and according to the associated [github issue](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/2095)

> the problem does no longer occur in the latest version 1.21.0 of PyMuPDF.

But while there might not be a warning in Adobe Acrobat anymore, a look into the files here reveals errors already in the content streams of the [original file](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/files/10130886/test_file.pdf) and even more errors in those of in the [redacted file](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/files/10130954/test_file_ANON.pdf).

These errors are of two types:

- Invalid use of text-positioning instructions outside of text objects.
- Invalid use of color setting instructions between path definition and path drawing instructions.

(There might be other errors still but these two types really leapt out at me.)

For example, the respectively first content stream of the original and the redacted file starts like this:

```
q
.1 w
0 .1 595.3 841.9 re
W*
n
q
/F1 10 Tf
1 0 0 1 311.9 693.5 Tm
Q
q
/F1 10 Tf
1 0 0 1 349.7 693.5 Tm
Q
...
```

Here **Tm** instructions are used outside of text objects which is not allowed, cf. *Figure 9 – Graphics Objects* of ISO 32000.

And in the additions to the content streams in the redacted file, there are blocks like this:

```
258.8 313.181 37.2084 7.17188 re
h
1 1 1 rg
1 1 1 RG
B
```

Here color instructions are used between the path construction and the path painting operators which is not allowed either, see the same figure as referenced above.

Common viewers appear to be quite lax about these errors (Acrobat, for example, does not complain about the issues in the original file) but they are errors nonetheless and can eventually cause issues.